# Consider supporting of other related proposals on AREA 51

Tags: discussion

There are currently some proposals that could help attracting more experts to history.SE. Have a look and follow if interested. Thanks.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22748/paleontology
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502/biology
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34955/futurology
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17859/geology
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21061/latin-language-usage

Answer (score 2):

While I think these are good causes, and honestly I would find a couple of them very interesting reads, I have to admit I fail to see how they would bring more experts to THIS site. If anything they would bring experts AWAY from this site when they come to beta and beyond.

Comment: strange reasoning, esp. for interdisciplinary field like history. You need experts in languages for translation, paleontology, geology to date events. Sites like theoretical computer science or theo. physics attract more user to SE network... most prof. historians or geologists will rather join one of above proposals regularly and come here from time to time, as these sites can answer questions where they suffer from expert knowledge. If you want more experts, you need se.sites that are related directly and indirectly to this topic, as here these experts/students have questions

Comment: thats the reason why so much physicists did join stackoverflow, a lot deal with programming problems in their job, and why the biology, medicine proposals are still in commitment

Answer (score 1):

The only one on this list that I'd consider "related" is palentology.